# How to strip off all but audio from an mp4 file?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, convert, mp4

I have an `.mp4` file with both audio and visual, however I want an `.mp4` file with just audio, so how can I just strip off the rest? Is there an application which will allow me to do that? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Why do you want an mp4 that's only audio? why not an mp3, flac, ogg, or anything else?

Comment: @Hellreaver what is the problem with mp4? Its only a container. And using mp3 or some other format could reencode the content. Using ffmpeg with -acodec copy will just demultiplex audio only.

Comment: @incBrain it's a video container, which will be opened by default as a video. Not a huge issue, but it seems like it could complicate things.

Comment: @Hellreaver who says that? This isn't true! Meta information in mp4 says weather its video, audio, subtitles or all together. Why in world should it be opened as video? How do you initialize the video decoder if there is no video in it? And it's not a video container!!! But multimedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg. In Ubuntu, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

To convert any video simply run:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audiofile.mp4
```

An alternative is to use the arguably more syntactically correct extension `.m4a`:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audiofile.m4a
```